# PHP & MySQLi timeout

Tags: php, mysql, timeout, mysqli

Whenever I try to create a mysqli object, as in;

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(host, user, pass, database);
```

...the page just loads for around a minute, then stops, showing all the content of the page up until that line.

info() says that MySQLi (and MySQL if that matters) are enabled, and I can access the MySQL CLI. I'm also working on a local machine, not a remote server.

I feel like I've missed something obvious. Can anyone shed some light on it?

Edit: just for clarification, I am actually putting real values into the mysqli constructor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to change the [Windows hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) (un-commented the localhost line).

Answer (score 4):

The fourth parameter to the [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php) should be the database, not the table.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);
```

You might also want to try displaying the error message:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   die("MySQL Connect Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

A possible problem is if MySQL is not using the default port. You can add the port number as an optional parameter in the mysqli constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I meant database name. I have tried putting the error message code in, but nothing happens.

Comment: @Dt7: What string are you using as the hostname?

Comment: localhost....

If it's worth mentioning, the code worked perfectly on my last install. I just recently replaced my hard drive and re-installed everything, but now it's just not working.

Comment: @Dt7: Can you try running `netstat -a` from the command line and see if there is a connection in `LISTENING` state for `TCP 127.0.0.1:3306`?

Answer (score 0):

Really stupid thing happened to me:

> I had a firewall blocking my database connection. So a firewall
>   blocking the port will result in a timeout experience in your script.

Hope this helps someone.